# booting elasticsearch on machine with 2GB RAM

Tags: elasticsearch, heap-memory, elasticsearch-5

I continue to get following error while trying to run elasticsearch on a SSD machine with 2GB RAM.

```
elasticsearch[1234] : # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
elasticsearch[1234] : # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 1973026816 bytes for committing reserved memory.
```

I modified default config /etc/init.d/elasticsearch modified with following options

```
ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
ES_HEAP_SIZE=1g
```

I restarted elasticsearch but I continue to get the same error.

```
sudo /bin/systemctl restart elasticsearch.service
```

Any ideas?

Comment: hi were you able to use it on this 2gb RAM machine?  did ES get shut down randomly, or was it fairly stable?  i'm also wanting to run ES on a smaller machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set Xms and Xmx in the [jvm.options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/heap-size.html) file. (/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options)

You can also use environment variables (`ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1g -Xmx1g"`), but you need to comment out the settings in jvm.options for that to work.

PS: Assuming 5.x since you didn't specify the version.

Comment: I mentioned the version in tag.